# Check if my ip is unique compared with previous one

Tags: c#

I've made a simple app which is checking my ip. The idea is:

**1)** If I click a button, the app will check my ip and compare with previous ips

**2)** If my new ip is the same, like the previous, do nothing

**3)** If my new ip is different than previous and I've never had this ip before, increment `unique` and add to `dataGridRow1` new row

**4)** If my new ip is my default ip increment `my_ip`

**5)** If my new ip is different than previous, but I've been assigned to this ip before increment `duplicate` and add to `dataGridRow1` new row

**6)** Every `dataGrid1` BackColor row's which contains duplicated ip is red colored. If it contains default ip it's green colored

*Ok, let's go into the code:*

Global variables:

```
string old_ip = "";
string new_ip = "";
int new_row = 0;    //new added row position
int duplicate = 0;
int my_ip = 0;
int unique = 0;
```

Delay function

```
public void MyDelad(int milliseconds)
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    while (stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds <= (long)milliseconds)
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
}
```

Button_click event

```
    MyDelad(500);

    while (true)    //force obtain new_ip
    {

        try
        {
            new_ip = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("https://api.ipify.org");
        }

        catch
        {
            MyDelad(500);
            continue;
        }
        break;

    }

    if (old_ip != new_ip)   //compare old and new ip
    {
        unique++;
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new_ip);



        if (new_ip == "121.464.544.122")     //if new ip is my default
        {
            my_ip++;
            unique--; //if it's default ip instead of unique
            dataGridView1.Rows[new_row].Cells[0].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        }

        else         //check every row if ip existed before
        {



            for (int x = 0; x < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2; x++)  //check from first to penultimate row
            {
                if (dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[0].Value.ToString() == new_ip.ToString())
                {
                   duplicate++;
                }
            }

        }

        new_row++;  //increment new added row position


    }

    old_ip = new_ip;


}
```

**My first question there:** I've heard that using global variable is wrong. But if I would use local variable in `button_click` event it will reset the variable's value after every button click (for example the variable which stores the `unique` value). Should I use global variables then?

**Second question:** can I store the `unique` value in another way? Right now it is incrementing `unique` value if `old_ip != new_ip`. And there if `new_ip == '121.464.544.122'`, then it will subtract the `unique` value, because it's my default value.

**Third question:** how can I avoid "freezing" my application when I run `Button_Click` event?.

**Fourth question:** Do you have any ideas how to improve my code? Maybe it would be better to store the previous ip in a text file, or an array?

Answer (score 0):

Just some pointers...

For the data I would create just a simple class with the variables as properties. In your form, you can just have one instance of your class. This class could also have a Dictionary with all the ip addresses you've collected (as key) and the number of times you found them (as value). This will make searching for it easier as well.

As for freezing... You should execute the (blocking) code of the click event in a separate thread. Then you can also forget about the `MyDelad()` function with the `Application.DoEvents()` call. Of course you need to keep thread safety in mind...